# Trouble with Python order of operations/loop

Tags: python

I have some code that is meant to convert CSV files into tab delimited files. My problem is that I cannot figure out how to write the correct values in the correct order. Here is my code:

```
for file in import_dir:
    data = csv.reader(open(file))
    fields = data.next()
    new_file = export_dir+os.path.basename(file)
    tab_file = open(export_dir+os.path.basename(file), 'a+')
    for row in data:
        items = zip(fields, row)
        item = {}
        for (name, value) in items:
            item[name] = value.strip()
    tab_file.write(item['name']+'\t'+item['order_num']...)
    tab_file.write('\n'+item['amt_due']+'\t'+item['due_date']...)
```

Now, since both my `write` statements are in the `for row in data` loop, my headers are being written multiple times over. 
If I outdent the first `write` statement, I'll have an obvious formatting error. 
If I move the second `write` statement above the first and then outdent, my data will be out of order.
 What can I do to make sure that the first `write` statement gets written once as a header, and the second gets written for each line in the CSV file? How do I extract the first 'write' statement outside of the loop without breaking the dictionary? Thanks!

Comment: Why not https://code.google.com/p/csvfix/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `csv` module contains methods for writing as well as reading, making this pretty trivial:

```
import csv

with open("test.csv") as file, open("test_tab.csv", "w") as out:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    writer = csv.writer(out, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

No need to do it all yourself. Note my use of [the `with` statement](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRaKmobSXF4), which should always be used when working with files in Python.

Edit: Naturally, if you want to select specific values, you can do that easily enough. You appear to be making your own dictionary to select the values - again, the `csv` module provides `DictReader` to do that for you:

```
import csv

with open("test.csv") as file, open("test_tab.csv", "w") as out:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    writer = csv.writer(out, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow([row["name"], row["order_num"], ...])
```

As kirelagin points out in the commends, `csv.writerows()` could also be used, here with a [generator expression](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw):

```
writer.writerows([row["name"], row["order_num"], ...] for row in reader)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue lies in that I am not converting the entire csv file, only picking out specific values to plug into a specific template that our accounting software utilizes.

Comment: @DrydenLong You can still use this method, just modify the rows before you write them.

Comment: @Lattyware I see your point, I guess it's just simpler for me to visualize it this way... +1 for the better way to do it though haha

Comment: @Lattyware so I played with the example code in your edit, and I'm getting the same output. The issue is that the dictionary is being created in the `for row` loop, but my headers (which utilize said dictionary) need to be written outside of that loop and before the other rows. How can I make that happen? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to write the headers, just do `writer.writerow(reader.fieldnames)` - but if you are not writing the same data back, the headers are going to be different - just make a list containing the headers and write that.

Comment: @Lattyware yes, this writes the headers, but it writes them for each row in the file. If i move that statement outside of the loop, it will either be trying to write values that haven't been defined yet or will write the headers after the contents.

Comment: @DrydenLong If the headers are defined as the first row in the reader, then pull just that row with `next()`, construct and write the row, then loop over the rest to write it.

Comment: @Lattyware the headers aren't defined as the first row in the reader. In fact, the headers in the tab delimited file are some of the values from the CSV. Essentially, I need a way to append the values of `row["name"]` and `row{"order_num"]` to the beginning of the tab file.

Comment: Then read the data in first, and pull the parts you need from the data, before writing it out.

Answer (score 5):

Extract the code that writes the headers *outside* the main loop, in such a way that it only gets written exactly once at the beginning.

Also, consider using the [CSV module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) for writing  CSV files (not just for reading), don't reinvent the wheel!

Comment: I guess this is what I am asking, how do I extract that code?

Comment: @DrydenLong: Move it above the `for`, and outdent it to the same level as the `for` itself.

Comment: @abarnert wouldn't the line of code I outdent then have keys from a dictionary that hasn't yet been created?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out, but it's not the most elegant solutions. Basically, I just ran the first loop, wrote to the file, then ran it a second time and appended the results. See my code below. I would love any input on a better way to accomplish what I've done here. Thanks!

```
for file in import_dir:
    data = csv.reader(open(file))
    fields = data.next()
    new_file = export_dir+os.path.basename(file)
    tab_file = open(export_dir+os.path.basename(file), 'a+')
    for row in data:
        items = zip(fields, row)
        item = {}
        for (name, value) in items:
            item[name] = value.strip()
    tab_file.write(item['name']+'\t'+item['order_num']...)
tab_file.close()

for file in import_dir:
    data = csv.reader(open(file))
    fields = data.next()
    new_file = export_dir+os.path.basename(file)
    tab_file = open(export_dir+os.path.basename(file), 'a+')
    for row in data:
        items = zip(fields, row)
        item = {}
        for (name, value) in items:
            item[name] = value.strip()
        tab_file.write('\n'+item['amt_due']+'\t'+item['due_date']...)
tab_file.close()
```